# Парсинг SOAP XML в Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, soap

Не могу распарсить XML файл. Запрос ничего не возвращает:

```
with x as (select XMLTYPE(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header><CigWsHeader xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
  <Culture>ru-RU</Culture>
  <Password>Vfylfh12354</Password>
  <SecurityToken /><UserId>0</UserId>
  <UserName>CNTuser03</UserName>
  <Version>1_0</Version></CigWsHeader>
  </soap:Header><soap:Body>
  <GetReportResponse xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
  <GetReportResult><CigResult Version="3.0.1" xmlns="">
  <DateTime>23.12.2017 15:49:18</DateTime>
  <ReferenceId>10</ReferenceId>
  <ServiceName>Front Office WS</ServiceName>
  <ResultCulture>ru-RU</ResultCulture>
  <ResultCode>10</ResultCode><ResultDescription />
  <UsageIdentity /><Result><Root><Title name="tblTitle" title="Report" intitle="Report subject" />
  <Header name="tblHeader" EntityType="Individual" title="Extended" ReportCode="Report.ReportName.Advanced" intitle="Subject">
  <RegistrationID title="Reg id" value="1984725" />
  <DateOfBirth title="Date of birth" value="26.02.1988" />
  <Gender title="Gender" value="Male" />
  <Name title="Name" value="JOHN" />
  <Surname title="Surname" value="SMITH" />
  <CityOfBirth title="City of birth" value="New York" />
  <Education title="Edu" id="123" value="Master" />
  <MatrialStatus title="Marital st." id="45" value="Single" />
  <RegionOfBirth title="Region" value="NY" />
  <CountryOfBirth title="Country" value="USA" /></Header>
  </Root></Result></CigResult></GetReportResult></GetReportResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>') as xml from dual)
SELECT y.*
FROM x, XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd",
                                 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi",
                                 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap"),
                                 '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetReportResponse/GetReportResult/CigResult/Result/Root/Header/RegistrationID' PASSING x.xml
COLUMNS val VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'RegistrationID') y
;
```

Comment: А в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: Запрос ничего не возвращает, в запросе для примера я пытаюсь вытащить значение атрибута RegistrationID но без результатно.

Comment: Сразу так не соображу, в чём проблема. Посмотрите, я как то отвечал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918090/read-nested-xml-in-oracle-sql/46993839#46993839) на похожий вопрос. Для вас второй вариант релевантен.

Comment: И попытайтесь сократить xml до необходимого минимума, а не вставлять его как есть.

Comment: Пока видно, что в `columns` отсутсутвует тип . И `path` выглядит странно, где у вас `return`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, там должен быть RegistrationID, поправил код.

Comment: А тип? Колонок без типа не бывает. Потом должно работать.

Comment: Указал тип, также ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Пока с телефона я не могу помочь. Упрощайте xml пока не обнаружите ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Узлы `GetReportResponse` и `GetReportResult` объявлены в пространстве имён `xmlns="http://ws.info.com/"`. Надо указать это же пространство имён в `XMLNAMESPACES` предложении, и затем использовать его в *XQuery* и *XPath* выражениях как квалифицированные имена в функции `XMLTable`.

Выдержка из [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232):

> The XMLNAMESPACES clause contains a set of XML namespace declarations. These declarations are referenced by the XQuery expression (the evaluated XQuery_string), which computes the row, and by the XPath expression in the PATH clause of XML_table_column, which computes the columns for the entire XMLTable function. If you want to use qualified names in the PATH expressions of the COLUMNS clause, then you need to specify the XMLNAMESPACES clause.

В примере используются XML данные из вопроса, но для улучшения наглядности я удалил некоторые узлы и атрибуты сохранив структуру документа неизменной:

```
with xmldata as (
select xmltype ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Header>
        <CigWsHeader xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
            <UserName>CNTuser03</UserName>
        </CigWsHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetReportResponse xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
            <GetReportResult>
                <CigResult Version="3.0.1" xmlns="">
                    <ReferenceId>10</ReferenceId>
                    <ServiceName>Front Office WS</ServiceName>
                    <ResultCode>10</ResultCode>
                    <Result>
                        <Root>
                            <Header name="tblHeader">
                                <RegistrationID title="Reg id" value="1984725" />
                                <Name title="Name" value="JOHN"/>
                                <Surname title="Surname" value="SMITH"/>
                            </Header>
                        </Root>
                    </Result>
                </CigResult>
            </GetReportResult>
        </GetReportResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>') as doc 
from dual
)
select xtab.*
from xmldata x cross join xmltable (
    xmlnamespaces (
        'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap", 
        'http://ws.info.com/' as "ws"
    ),
    '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ws:GetReportResponse/ws:GetReportResult/
        CigResult/Result/Root/Header/RegistrationID' passing x.doc
    columns 
        "Title" varchar2 (32) path '@title',
        "Value" varchar2 (32) path '@value'
    ) xtab
;
```

Вывод:

```
Title                            Value                          
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
Reg id                           1984725
```

**На заметку**: Решение в ответе ТС, использующее поиск через `descendant::` (по оси потомков), также будет работать, но не рекомендуется по соображениям производительности, как было указано в [Белых книгах](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-features/xmldb/overview/xmldb-bpwp-12cr1-1964809.pdf) (см. стр. 32) о достижении макс. производительности XML запросов.

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем долго покопавшись, нашел выход. Кажется дело в неймспейсах которые указаны в GetReportResponse. Вот таким способом можно решить проблему:

```
WITH X AS (SELECT XMLTYPE(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Header>
        <CigWsHeader xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
        <Culture>ru-RU</Culture>
        <Password>Vfylfh12354</Password>
        <SecurityToken /><UserId>0</UserId>
        <UserName>CNTuser03</UserName>
        <Version>1_0</Version></CigWsHeader>
      </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <GetReportResponse xmlns="http://ws.info.com/">
      <GetReportResult><CigResult Version="3.0.1" xmlns="">
      <DateTime>23.12.2017 15:49:18</DateTime>
      <ReferenceId>10</ReferenceId>
      <ServiceName>Front Office WS</ServiceName>
      <ResultCulture>ru-RU</ResultCulture>
      <ResultCode>10</ResultCode><ResultDescription />
      <UsageIdentity />
    <Result>
     <Root>
      <Title name="tblTitle" title="Report" intitle="Report subject" />
      <Header name="tblHeader" EntityType="Individual" title="Extended" ReportCode="Report.ReportName.Advanced" intitle="Subject">
      <RegistrationID title="Reg id" value="1984725" />
      <DateOfBirth title="Date of birth" value="26.02.1988" />
      <Gender title="Gender" value="Male" />
      <Name title="Name" value="JOHN" />
      <Surname title="Surname" value="SMITH" />
      <CityOfBirth title="City of birth" value="New York" />
      <Education title="Edu" id="123" value="Master" />
      <MatrialStatus title="Marital st." id="45" value="Single" />
      <RegionOfBirth title="Region" value="NY" />
      <CountryOfBirth title="Country" value="USA" /></Header>
    </Root>
  </Result>
  </CigResult>
  </GetReportResult>
  </GetReportResponse>
  </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>') AS XML FROM DUAL)
SELECT y.*
  FROM x, XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap"),
                                 '*/*/*/*/*/*/Root/descendant::RegistrationID' PASSING x.xml
COLUMNS 
    title VARCHAR2(200) PATH '@title',
    val VARCHAR2(200) PATH '@value') y
  ;
```